# Initialize weights as identity matrix in Tensorflow NN model

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am relatively new to the work of Neural Network in one of the models on GitHub I noticed that after initializing the weights and biases as zero, an identity matrix was added to the biases variable.

```
 weights = tf.get_variable('weights', [256, K*K],
                              initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0),
                              dtype=tf.float32)
 biases = tf.get_variable('biases', [K*K],
                             initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0),
                             dtype=tf.float32)
 biases += tf.constant(np.eye(K).flatten(), dtype=tf.float32)
 transform = tf.matmul(net, weights)
 transform = tf.nn.bias_add(transform, biases)
```

Is it particular to this model or is this the a common practice? If so, what is the purpose served by initializing biases as identity matrix?

Link to the repo: [Here](https://github.com/charlesq34/pointnet)
Link to the paper: [Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.00593.pdf)

Comment: Which file in the repo is the code excerpt from?

Comment: transform_nets.py

Answer (score 0):

Initializing all weights to zero is actually a really bad idea. If you do this, the output of your neural network is going to be always zero, because no matterwhat the value of your input is, if you are multiplying it by zero, you get zero as output.

For neural networks it is a common practice to initialize the weights and biases with random noise between -1 and 1.

I personally use [Xavier initialization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/xavier_initializer), which is designed to keep the scale of the gradients approximately the same in all layers, therefore improving convergence.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about initializing a matrix for biases.

Comment: If I understand the paper correctly, the network is trying to be invariant to the permutation/order of the points. Because it is working with unordered point sets(3D points) the network will deal with a point cloud of no order whatsoever. So in order to make it invariant, they have initialized the weights to zero and biases to an identity matrix. That is my understanding so far.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your weights to zeroes is not what you want. As fPecc said random noise is a good inizialization, otherwise you could try normal distribution.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand it correctly but I believe it has something to do with the implementation of a symmetric function on the points. Here is a link of the author explaining PointNet:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cge-hot0Oc0&t=434s